# How do I pivot over date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks like this

```
date     lat long 
1/2/12   30   30
2/2/12   31   12
2/2/12   30   29
2/2/12   30   30
3/2/12   31   21
3/2/12   31   10
3/2/12   nan  nan
      ....
5/15/20  31   21
5/16/20  21   05
5/18/20  nan nan
```

I want to get a table that looks like the following. Basically, each date column now contains the total count of a matching lat/long until that specific date

```
 lat long 1/2/12  2/2/12 3/2/12 ... 5/15/20 5/16/20 5/17/20 ...
  30   30   1       2      2          11      55      67
  31   12   0       1      1          1        1      3
  30   29   0       1      1          17      22     25
  30   30   0       1      2          100     130    145
```

and so on.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab([df['lat'],df['long']], df.date).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
date   lat  long  1/2/12  2/2/12  3/2/12  5/15/20  5/16/20
0     21.0   5.0       0       0       0        0        1
1     30.0  29.0       0       1       0        0        0
2     30.0  30.0       1       1       0        0        0
3     31.0  10.0       0       0       1        0        0
4     31.0  12.0       0       1       0        0        0
5     31.0  21.0       0       0       1        1        0
```